# Does anyone know where I can find cheat codes for Goldeneye 007 Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, cheats, goldeneye-007

I know that the game hasn't even been out for a week, but does anyone know if any cheat codes have been released by Activision yet?

I know that they must exist since there is a cheat codes menu within the game.

Comment: Didn't the original game have cheat codes unlocked by beating certain missions under a "par time"?

Comment: Yep! Does anyone know if the same is true for the Wii version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheat codes menu within the game is for players who pre-ordered the game from various retailers. These codes only work in splitscreen multiplayer, and are only exclusive to these pre-orders until the end of the year.

- BestBuy: "Tag Mode" - The person "tagged" cannot kill until they are no longer "it."
- Gamestop: "Invisibility Mode" - Each player can go invis for a small period of time to sneak up on other players.

It hasn't been stated yet how players can obtain these codes after this time. No other cheats have been released at the time of this posting.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully more information will become available in 2011.

Answer (score 3):

The pre-order cheats have been posted in [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/997757-goldeneye-007/cheats):

> - **Big Heads**  <477MYFR13NDS4R3SP13S>
> - **Invisibility Modifier (Split    Screen)**   Inv1s1bleEv3ryth1ng
> - **Tag    Modifier (Split Screen)** NotIt!!!11